# ¿Cómo hacer que se ejecute un Intent dentro de mi aplicación sin salirse?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

Quiero que mi aplicación sea capaz de mandar a llamar una aplicación con un *Intent*, y que esta se ejecute dentro mi aplicación como estilo *WebView*. El motivo es que quiero monitorear el proceso que se desencadena, y frecuentemente colocar una cierta publicidad.

Comment: has visto una aplicación que realiza esto, sería bueno explicaras un poco más : "La razón que me interesa es porque quiero monitorear el proceso que se desencadena y en vez encunado colocar una cierta publicidad. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Por cuestiones de seguridad no es posible abrir una aplicación dentro de otra.**

Lo máximo que puedes realizar es permitir a la aplicación ser abierta por medio de un `Intent` por otra aplicación pero nunca dentro de otra.

Comment: Pero no habrá una forma de enviar publicidad a ella?.

Comment: Tienes definido que tipo de publicidad, google ads, oas, dfp, dime un poco más ?

Comment: Y ademas ver si termino el trabajo, como un ejemplo creo en mi app derivadas funciones como abrir archivos de textos, mp3, etc. Y que yo ejecute un Intent llamando a una aplicación y que yo sea capas de saber termino de verlo o escucharlo y ademas enviar algunas publicidad mientras este ejecuta el archivo que yo le otorgue prácticamente ?. Gracias

Comment: No todavia la he incluido porque no he finalizado el proyecto, tal vez lo deje de ultimo, pero si es seguro que usare google ads o admob.

Comment: Ya! por ejemplo usando un startActivity(Intent.createChooser() abre una aplicación para reproducir un mp3 , u otro tipo d archivo, aquí lo único que puedes detectar es que cerraste la pantalla y puedes regresar a la aplicación original un código que indique se realizo determinada acción.

Comment: Gracias el me has dado una idea para saber cuando ocurre un proceso, pero no sabrás si es posible lo de la publicidad.